# Error with MainActivity$2 symbol but not actually associate with activity?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to coding and android studio and currently working on a homework assignment to develop a `quiz app`. The app was running fine until I got this error:

> Type com.example.quizapp.MainActivity$2 is defined multiple times:
>   /Users/laurapaulino/Desktop/Mobile
>   Computing/QuizApp2/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/quizapp/MainActivity$2
>   2.class, /Users/laurapaulino/Desktop/Mobile Computing/QuizApp2/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/quizapp/MainActivity$2.class

package com.example.quizapp;

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

class MainActivity$2 implements OnClickListener {
    MainActivity$2(MainActivity this$0) {
        this.this$0 = this$0;
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (this.this$0.answer2.getText() == MainActivity.access$000(this.this$0)) {
            MainActivity.access$108(this.this$0);
            this.this$0.score.setText("Score: " + MainActivity.access$100(this.this$0));
            MainActivity.access$300(this.this$0, this.this$0.r.nextInt(MainActivity.access$200(this.this$0)));
        } else {
            MainActivity.access$400(this.this$0);
        }

    }
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sztym.png)

This is how my Main Activity class looks like. Can't find where the error is...

```
package com.example.quizapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;

    TextView score, question;

    private Questions mQuestions = new Questions();

    private String mAnswers;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionsLength = mQuestions.mQuestions.length;

    Random r;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        r = new Random();

        answer1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer1);
        answer2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer2);
        answer3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer3);
        answer4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer4);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);

        score.setText("Score: " + mScore);

        updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));

        answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (answer1.getText() == mAnswers){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                } else {
                    gameOver();
                }
            }

        });


        answer2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (answer2.getText() == mAnswers){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                } else {
                    gameOver();
                }
            }

        });

        answer3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (answer3.getText() == mAnswers){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                } else {
                    gameOver();
                }
            }

        });

        answer4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (answer4.getText() == mAnswers){
                    mScore++;
                    score.setText("Score: " + mScore);
                    updateQuestion(r.nextInt(mQuestionsLength));
                } else {
                    gameOver();
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void updateQuestion(int num ) {
        question.setText(mQuestions.getQuestion(num));
        answer1.setText(mQuestions.getChoice1(num));
        answer2.setText(mQuestions.getChoice2(num));
        answer3.setText(mQuestions.getChoice3(num));
        answer4.setText(mQuestions.getChoice4(num));

        mAnswers = mQuestions.getCorrectAnswer(num);
    }

    private void gameOver() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Game Over! Your score is " + mScore + " points.")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("NEW GAME",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("EXIT",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
}
```

Second Java Class:

```
package com.example.quizapp;

public class Questions {
    public String mQuestions[] = {
            "Who is the oldest Belcher kid?",
            "What is Linda's sister's name?",
            "Where do Linda's parents live?",
            "What is Bob's favorite holiday?",
            "Who is Bob's best friend?",
            "Who is Bob's arch enemy?",
            "What is Louise's favorite toy?",
            "Who was Gene's first girlfriend?",
            "Who did Gayle have a big crush on in high school?"
    };

    private String mChoices[][] = {
            //"Tina", "Gayle", "Florida", "Thanksgiving", "Teddy", "Jimmy Pesto", "Kuchi Kopi", "Courtney", "Derek Dematopolis"
            {"Tina", "Courtney", "Louise", "Gene"},
            {"Gretchen", "Teddy", "Gayle", "Maria"},
            {"New Jersey", "New York", "King's Head Island", "Florida"},
            {"Halloween", "Thanksgiving", "Christmas", "Easter"},
            {"Mr. Fischoeder", "Gayle", "Teddy", "Hugo"},
            {"Jimmy Pesto", "Mr. Fischoeder", "Ron", "Randy"},
            {"Teddy Bear", "Rare Pony", "Kuchi Kopi", "Tricycle"},
            {"Millie", "Tammy", "Jocelyn", "Courtney"},
            {"Gretchen", "Felix Fischoeder", "Dr. Yap", "Derek Dematopolis"},
    };


    private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {"Tina", "Gayle", "Florida", "Thanksgiving", "Teddy", "Jimmy Pesto", "Kuchi Kopi", "Courtney", "Derek Dematopolis"};

    public String getQuestion (int a) {
        String question = mQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }

    public String getChoice1(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][0];
        return choice;
    }

    public String getChoice2(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][1];
        return choice;
    }

    public String getChoice3(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][2];
        return choice;
    }

    public String getChoice4(int a) {
        String choice = mChoices[a][3];
        return choice;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
        return answer;
    }

}
```

There is no indication of an error on the actual classes but I can't run the program on the emulator. I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual error?  It just looks like code.

Comment: Why are you editing or trying to edit this class?  Its a generated class (originally the second annonymous inner class in MainActivity), you should be editing the actual java file MainActivity.java, not this.

Comment: Hi, I wasn't actually editing that page. It's what opened when I clicked on the error. I updated the question, hopefully it's more clear, sorry first time posting!

Answer (score 1):

I was stucked in the same problem.....
SOLUTION: click on BUILD -> clean project and then
click on BUILD -> rebuild project.

Hope this will work :)